# Linux GCC Makefile a shared library with multply sources and dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I have a problem trying to create a Makefile that compile multiple sorces, generate only a shared library and make an exe with another file wiht the main function.

The sorces also have dependencies.

My Makefile is

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
BINS=libsensorMotor.so maintarget

all: $(BINS)

libsensorMotor.o: libsensorMotor.cpp sensorMotor.h Adafruit_ADS1015.cpp Adafruit_ADS1015.h wiringPiI2C.c wiringPiI2C.h enumADCGain.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c libsensorMotor.cpp Adafruit_ADS1015.cpp wiringPiI2C.c

libsensorMotor.so: libsensorMotor.cpp sensorMotor.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ libsensorMotor.cpp -lc

maintarget: maintarget.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L. -lsensorMotor -pthread

clean:
    rm *.o $(BINS)
```

The script show the errors:

```
 libsensorMotor.so  Undefined reference to 'functionXXXX'
```

maintarget contains the main and use libsensorMotor as a shared library. libsensorMotor depends and include all the rest of the files

The error mention all the functions that libsensorMotor uses from the include sources.

I only need to generate a correct libsensorMotor.so that can use as shared library from any other main file. Internet has many tutorials but are unclear, weird and complicated,  and not show how do this simple.

Comment: where is defined the functionXXXX ?

Comment: You're only compiling one file (libsensorMotor.cpp) when building your shared library.

Comment: functionXXXX is any function declared in the Adafruit_ADS1015.cpp or  wiringPiI2C.c, used by libsensormotor

Comment: Then need a .so declaration in Makefile for each source file? , Im sorry, I really not understood well how this work, I only need one shared library (libsensorMotor.so) The thing is that libsensorMotor.so have dependency from Adafruit_ADS1015.cpp and this have dependences with wiringPiI2C.c .
I dont want 3 shared libraries that need to be add each at compiling maintarget.c

Answer (score 0):

Is not Makefile problem, simply the line

gcc -pthread -lm -o maintarget maintarget.c libsensorMotor.cpp Adafruit_ADS1015.cpp wiringPiI2C.c

sends same error, the compiler not recongnice the function inside the pthread_create while compile C and C++ with gcc